# propogating signal to child processes

Tags: c, bash

I have a collection of processes that I'm starting from a shell script as follows:

```
#!/bin/bash
#This is a shortcut to start multiple storage services

function finish {
    alljobs=$(jobs -p)
    if [ ! -z "$alljobs" ]; then
        kill $alljobs >/dev/null 2>&1
    else
        echo "Entire trio ceased running"
    fi
}
trap finish EXIT

./storage &
P1=$!
./storage &
P2=$!
./storage &
P3=$!
wait $P1 $P2 $P3
```

Currently, it executes how I want it to, in that when I send a `ctrl+c` signal to it, the script sends that signal to all my background processes.

However: I've now extended these programs so that, based on connections/messages they receive from clients, they may do an `execv`, killing themselves and starting up a new, separate program. (For the curious, they're simulating a "server dead" state by starting up an idling process, which may then receive signals to start up the original process again.)

The problem is that, after the `execv`, this new process no longer responds to a `kill` sent by the bash script.

Is there a way to allow for this original script's execution (and subsequent signalling) to also send a signal to the newly `exec`'d process as well?

Comment: why you use  C++ in your tag?

Comment: Sorry, perhaps `c` would be more appropriate; I anticipate the answer may involve some modification to the `execv` call, or the way the programs are created, which is all currently in c++

Answer (score 1):

I suggest you consider searching for child processes by the parent pid.  More specifically, before killing a pid, search for the child processes of that pid using ps and kill those children first.  Finally, kill the parent.

I have a feeling that there are race conditions that will cause this to fail in some cases.

Answer (score 0):

Update: my issue was completely unrelated to this script; the `pid` of the running/rebooted processes never changed, but I was inadvertently inheriting the signals I was blocking in various threads internal to the program. Some sensible calls to `pthread_sigmask` solved the issue.

Thanks to @Mark for the tips about child processes though; if there were `fork` calls going on, that would have been a very good approach!